# From my understanding this lambda call should be invalid, but it does not crash. Why?

Tags: c++11, lambda

I am having trouble understanding why the following code does not crash.

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() {    m_contents = 0xF0F0F0F0; }
    void Hello() { printf("Hello, address: %llx, contents: %x, size: %d\n", (long long int)this, m_contents, sizeof(MyClass)); }
    int m_contents;
};

int main()
{
    MyClass* MyObj = new MyClass();
    MyObj->Hello();

    auto MyLambda = [MyObj]()
    {
        if (MyObj != nullptr)
        {
            MyObj->Hello();
        }
    };

    memset(MyObj, 0, sizeof(MyClass));
    MyObj->Hello();
    delete MyObj;
    MyObj = nullptr;

    MyLambda();

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
Hello, address: 1ddb4a16100, contents: f0f0f0f0, size: 4
Hello, address: 1ddb4a16100, contents: 0, size: 4
Hello, address: 1ddb4a16100, contents: dddddddd, size: 4
```

I would have expected the lambda call to crash because I wiped out all the memory that it is using to call the Hello() function. I know the contents are wiped because m_contents becomes 0. After calling delete, m_contents becomes a random value, but still, Hello() is called and there is no crash.

Follow up question:
In a lambda where I pass *this* as a capture, is there a chance that *this* becomes null or invalid by the time the lambda is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[MyObj]() { }` does not capture the pointer `MyObj` by reference, but by value. That means that the value of `MyObj` will be copied at the time of creation of the lambda. So even after you set `MyObj` to nullptr, the lambda will still use its original value, which still points to the same area in memory.

At the time you call the lambda, the object at `*MyObj` has already been deleted, which can be seen by all the `0xdd` bytes (at least in Debug mode).

If you were to write `[&MyObj]() { }` then `MyObj` would be captured as a reference, meaning the lambda will always use the current value of the captured pointer. In that case, the behavior should be exactly as you expected in the first place: the nullptr check in your lambda would fail and `Hello()` would not be called.

As for your follow up question: Passing `this` does work no different than any other symbol. Passing it by value will create a copy which will always allow you access to the object, even after its lifetime (with all the risks resulting from that). Passing it by reference will work as long the this pointer is valid, which will probably be as long as the scope of the method is valid.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer Thomas. I changed ```[MyObj]()``` to ```[&MyObj]()``` and the program behaved exactly as you described.